# Less grandparent has class selector

Tags: css, sass, less

I have a class like:

```css
.item
{
    svg
    {
        fill: var(--theme-font-color-extra-light);
    }

    &.active
    {
        svg
        {
            fill: var(--theme-main-color);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any selector or way to achieve the same result but with something similar to the following code in less:

```css
.item
{
    svg
    {
        fill: var(--theme-font-color-extra-light);

        @selector executed if div having .item also has .active (.item.active)
        {
            fill: var(--theme-main-color);
        }
    }
}
```

**[EDIT 12/11/2019]**
Using the following code does not work:

```css
.item
{
    svg
    {
        fill: var(--theme-font-color-extra-light);

        .active&
        {
            fill: var(--theme-main-color);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a bit confused as to why it does not work but apparently VS Code tells me that this code is transpiled as:

[image]

(Without the tooltip):

[image]

**[EDIT 12/12/2019]**
The full code block looks like this:

[image]

and as pointed out by @chazsolo in the comments there is no selector to achieve such a thing in this case.

Comment: @disinfor No, see the edit

Comment: @disinfor Still not, unfortunately that's in SCSS

Comment: Fair enough. The first code block in the answer below works if you test it at: https://lesstester.com/

Comment: @disinfor Okay after investigating it does not work for my special case only thus making it a duplicated as you suggested, I voted to close this topic. Thanks

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt wait a second - I just realized in your screenshot you are using `&` to prefix the `.item` class - could you show the entire code block?

Comment: @chazsolo Sure, it goes as follows: https://imgur.com/a/HgzIHug

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt considering you've got `#menu` as part of the selector, there's no way to use `&` to apply `.active` strictly to `.item`

Comment: @chazsolo Oh okay I should have clarified that from the beginning, thanks you've answered my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**LESS**

You can use the [parent selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) to achieve this - just note the position of the `&`

```
.item {
  svg {
    fill: red;

    .active& { // <-- no space between .active and &
      fill: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's some examples of what changing the placement will do to change the evaluated selector:

```
.active&  // .active.item svg (what you want)
.active & // .active .item svg
&.active  // .item svg.active
& .active // .item svg .active
```

---

**SASS**

Note that placing an `&` at the end of a compound selector is not allowed in SASS ([yet](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1425)).

However, you can use the `@at-root` directive to get the same output:

```
.item {
  svg {
    fill: red;

    @at-root .active#{&} { // <-- directive + interpolation #{&}
      fill: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That what I tried at first but it did not work and I did not exactly understood why, it's for this reason that I'm asking here (see the edit)

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt is it just VS code showing you the wrong tooltip? This works using online playgrounds for both LESS and SASS.

Comment: Oh really, I really don't know where I don't get it, would you help me ? Here I made a sandbox illustrating my case https://codepen.io/akronae/pen/LYEZEry

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt in your codepen: change `color` to `background-color` and you get the result you are looking for - the inner-most square turns purple. Is that not correct?

Comment: oh yeah.. what a dumb mistake! That's correct I'll investigate why it does not work for my special case thanks